# I downloaded FDFToolkitForJava , and I put the JAR file in my classpath. How exactly you create a FDF template? any step by step document?

Tags: java, pdf, ms-office, fdf

How do I create a FDF Template. Using that Template when we input the data suitable for Template , A PDF should be generated.

1) A user designs a template in MS word. (Assume Last name, First name)

2) Anybody should be able to use that template and type in last name and firstname.

3) A pdf should be generated based on template and data input given.

trying to use Adobe FDF , any insights is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Because you need a fillable PDF form in order to use the FDFToolkit, you first create such a form in Acrobat, starting from your Word file.

When done, fill it out, and export the data as FDF.

And that's how your FDF has to look like.

As good as the FDFToolkit is for reading and interpreting FDFs, in my experience, it is easier to assemble the FDF from according strings, and not bother with the FDFToolkit.